# Model form save. Get the saved object

Tags: django, django-forms

If I have a model form and save it like:

```
f = FormModel(request.POST)
if f.is_valid():
    f.save()
```

How can I get back that object that has just been saved?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

When you save a modelform, it returns the saved instance of the model.  So all you have to do is assign it to a variable:

```
f = MyModelForm(request.POST)
if f.is_valid():
    m = f.save()
```

You do not need to mess around with `commit=False` or any of that stuff unless you are handling more complex data.

Comment: can you explain this concept in bit more depth ?

Answer (score 30):

If you know that the model is saved (so that a proper instance exists) you can also do:

```
model = form.instance
```

Answer (score 8):

Ah I just found this!

```
    # Create a form instance with POST data.
>>> f = AuthorForm(request.POST)

# Create, but don't save the new author instance.
>>> new_author = f.save(commit=False)

# Modify the author in some way.
>>> new_author.some_field = 'some_value'

# Save the new instance.
>>> new_author.save()

# Now, save the many-to-many data for the form.
>>> f.save_m2m()
```

Answer (score 0):

@Fabian, that's for editing an instance that wasn't previously included in your model form,

E.g your model form covers name, age, gender but in your model there is another field maybe country and you want to add it by yourself not your user, so you reveal the required fields and then you use the above procedure to add the rest
This worked for me on the above prob

```
If form.is_valid()
    Current_form=form.save()
    My_new_id=Curret_form.id
```

This printed the id of the newly created objected which I later saved in another model