# Why does django ORM's `save` method not return the saved object?

Tags: django, orm, django-models

Any insight into the reasoning behind this design decision? It seems to me that having `obj.save()` return *something*, has only benefits (like method chaining) and no drawbacks.

Answer (score 74):

It's generally considered good practice in Python to have functions that primarily affect existing objects *not* return themselves.  For instance, `sorted(yourlist)` returns a sorted list but `yourlist.sort()` sorts the list in-place and does not return anything.

Performing multiple operations with side-effects (as opposed to no-side-effect functions where the focus is on the return value) on a single line is not really good practice.  The code will be more compact in terms of number of lines, but it will be harder to read because important side-effects may be buried in the middle of a chain.  If you want to use method chaining, use functions with no side effects in the beginning of the chain and then have a single function with a side effect like `.save()` at the end.

To put it another way, in a method chain, the beginning of the chain is the input, the middle of the chain transforms the input (navigating down a tree, sorting the input, changing case of a string etc) and the end of the chain is the functional part that does work with side-effects.  If you bury methods with side-effects in the middle of the chain then it will be unclear what your method chain actually does.

Comment: actualy save() returns the saved object , maybe it is new on django 1.5 ?

Comment: @maazza I just tried this on Django 1.5.1 and save() still returns None.  [The source code for the latest dev version](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L492) also doesn't appear to return anything.

Comment: true , i used a modelform http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428245/model-form-save-get-the-saved-object

Comment: @maazza Oh, I see.  I feel that is a different case in that you are calling .save() on a form and it is returning a different object, not itself.

FWIW I think it would be cleaner if ModelForm did not have a .save() and instead had a method to instantiate an object in memory without side-effects, just like User() instantiates a User object.  Then you can call .save() on that.  But that is just my personal opinion, and there may be other issues I haven't considered that preclude doing that.

Comment: This answer is probably best, but if you want to return an object, just use `.save(commit=False)`.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Answer (score 8):

This reminds me of the general principle that Greg Ward [espoused](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9cnHO15YgU#t=11m50s) at Pycon2015 recently, not to confuse functions with procedures. Every function should return a value or have a side-effect, but not both.

Basically the same question [is asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452995/why-doesnt-a-python-dict-update-return-the-object) of dict.update().

Answer (score 5):

Since this is the first result that I get when searching for "django return saved object", to compliment Andrew's answer, if you still want to return the saved object, instead of using:

```py
ExampleModel(title=title).save()
```

which returns None, you'd use:

```py
saved_instance = ExampleModel.objects.create(title=title)
```

And this works because `ExampleModel.objects` is a [Model Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/) rather than an instance of the class, so it's not returning itself.