# implementing add and iadd for custom class in python?

Tags: python, class, object, addition, in-place

I am  writing a `Queue` class that wraps list for most of its operations. But I do not sublcass from `list`, since I do not want to provide all the `list API's`. I have my code pasted below. The `add` method seems to work fine, but `iadd` seems to go wrong, it is printing none.
Here is the code:

```
import copy
from iterator import Iterator
class Abstractstruc(object):
    def __init__(self):
        assert False
    def __str__(self):
        return "<%s: %s>" %(self.__class__.__name__,self.container)

class Queue(Abstractstruc,Iterator):

    def __init__(self,value=[]):
        self.container=[]
        self.size=0
        self.concat(value)

    def add(self, data):
            self.container.append(data)
    def __add__(self,other):
        return Queue(self.container + other.container)


    def __iadd__(self,other):
        for i in other.container:
            self.add(i)

    def  remove(self):
        self.container.pop(0)


    def peek(self):
        return self.container[0]


    def __getitem__(self,index):
        return self.container[index]


    def __iter__(self):
        return Iterator(self.container)

    def concat(self,value):
        for i in value:
            self.add(i)

    def __bool__(self):
        return len(self.container)>0

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.container)


    def __deepcopy__(self,memo):
        return Queue(copy.deepcopy(self.container,memo))


if __name__=='__main__':
    q5 = Queue()
    q5.add("hello")

    q6 = Queue()
    q6.add("world")

    q5 = q5+q6

    print q5
    q5+=q6
    print q5
```

Output:

```
<Queue: ['hello', 'world']>
None
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`__iadd__` needs to return `self` when adding in-place:

```
def __iadd__(self,other):
    for i in other.container:
        self.add(i)
    return self
```

`__iadd__` needs to return the resulting object; for immutable types the new object, for mutable types, `self`. Quoting the [in-place operator hooks documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__):

> These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying `self`) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, `self`).

Comment: adding `return self` works. I thought I am changing the mutable instance attribute, so I dont have to return self..just like my `add` method above. in case of `__add__` I am returning a new objecct, so a return is needed. for `__iadd__` since it is in-place addition, I was under the wrong impression that changing the state of self will directly reflect.

Comment: @user1988876: If you use your original `+=`, and keep another reference to the object so you can check it, you'll see that it actually _is_ mutating the original object, it's just that it's _also_ rebinding the name to `None`. You want it to mutate the original object, and also keep the name bound to `self`.

Comment: @abarnert I didn't know that, thank you! This makes a lot more sense now.