# Why does Python assign None if you add a variable to a set while assigning it

Tags: python, set

Instead of adding a variable to a set correctly, e.g.:

```
 set_to_add_to = set()
 set_to_add_to.add("test")
```

I just accidentally coded:

```
 set_to_add_to = set()
 set_to_add_to = set_to_add_to.add("test")
```

While I appreciate that this is not how you should add items to a set, it surprised me that the above resulted in `set_to_add_to` taking the value `None`. I couldn't work out why that would happen: it seems analogous to `int_variable = int_variable + 5`, which works correctly.

Similarly:

```
 set_to_add_to = set()
 new_set = set_to_add_to.add("test")
```

results in `new_set` taking the value `None` — why is it not the case that `"test"` is added to `set_to_add_to` and then that assigned to `new_set`?

Comment: The .add("test") call adds "test" to the set, but the function itself returns None. You should not be assigning new_set, instead put the assignment and the .add() call on different lines. i.e. set_to_add_to.add("test") is all you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it is import to note all functions (including user-defined and built-in functions) return something.  Usually, it is easy to see what a function returns by its `return` statement.  In a function without a `return` statement, `None` is returned by default.

Now, for the rationale behind why some python commonly used functions return None.

In general, python functions that modify objects in place return None.

For example:

```
x = [4,3,7,8,2]
y = sorted(x) #y is now a sorted list because sorted returns a copy!
y = x.sort() # y is now None because x was sorted in place
```

A notable exception is the `pop()` function which returns the value being popped.

Check out this post for a more detailed explanation:

[Is making in-place operations return the object a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062423/is-making-in-place-operations-return-the-object-a-bad-idea)

```
x = [4,3,7,8,2]
val = x.pop() 

#val = 2
#x = [4,3,7,8]
```

Comment: As OP is new to Python, you may want to add that *all* functions return *something*, but *something* is None if `return` is omitted

Answer (score 1):

The `.add()` method for sets always returns `None`, in the same way that the `.append()` list method returns `None` for example.