# Unusual program flow and variable modification in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, sequential

I am trying to fix my thresholding function as it did not appear to work correctly. This is when I came across a strange phenomena that really makes me think there is something I really don't understand about Python/programming.
    `

```
b = c
c = thresh(c)
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(b,cmap='gray'),plt.title('C')
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow((c),cmap='gray'),plt.title('C tresh')   
plt.show()
```

This is the erroneous code, I was trying to compare side by side to see the effects my thresholding function `tresh()` had on the image I am manipulating.

Both images displayed below are the same even though the thresholding function has been applied to only one of the variables being displayed, namely c. Variable `b` is not modified in anyway before being displayed, yet it is displayed in same way as `c` which has been thresholded.

[image]

```
b = c

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(b,cmap='gray'),plt.title('C')
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(thresh(c),cmap='gray'),plt.title('C tresh') 
plt.show()
```

I tried to fix it by having the thresholding performed implicitly inside of the `imshow()` function and to my surprise it worked.

[image]

I can not think of a way to explain why the original code snippet produced same images and why my "fix" managed to produce two different images.

thresholding function,

```
def thresh(image):
    x = len(image)
    y = len(image[0])
    tresh = 180
    for ix in range(x):
        for iy in range(y):
            if image[ix][iy] <tresh:
                image[ix][iy] = 0   
    return image
```

Comment: what is the "thresh" function? where does it come from?

Comment: Are you sure that `thresh` doesn't modify its argument? What happens if you do `b = c.copy(); c=thresh(c)`?

Comment: I added the function. @user8153 I will try that

Comment: Indeed it looks like your `thresh` function modifies its argument directly. It also doesn't provide a return value.

Comment: There was return, I just didn't paste it in properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to the two facts:  Python pass argument by assignment (in your case `image` inside your function, `b` and `c` refer to the same object), and lists are mutable object (you can modify to states of the object).

So when you are modifying `image` inside `thresh`, your are modifying the underlying object and thus `b` and `c`.

To avoid the issue, you need to pass a copy of `b` to the function (see this [question and corresponding answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744113/python-list-by-value-not-by-reference) for more info on the different ways to achieve it).

In your case, you need to change your code to:

```
from copy import deepcopy
b = deepcopy(c)
c = thresh(c)
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(b,cmap='gray'),plt.title('C')
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow((c),cmap='gray'),plt.title('C tresh')   
plt.show()
```

Also note that you don't need to return `image` at the end of your function in this case.

Comment: Thanks. When should/shouldn't you use return in python then?

Comment: This is a huge question. This is purely option, but if I create new values, I return them. If I modify in place, I return None. See [this stack overflow questions for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062423/is-making-in-place-operations-return-the-object-a-bad-idea?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)