# Equivalent of pandas .append() method, which allows method chaining

Tags: python, pandas, method-chaining

Now that `append()` is removed in pandas 2.0, what is a short alternative to `append()` allowing method chaining?
The ["What’s new in 2.0.0"](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html) section of pandas says:

> Removed deprecated `Series.append()`, `DataFrame.append()`, use `concat()`
> instead [(GH 35407)](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35407)

I am looking for something like below to add one row, but within a method chain.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 5, 6],
                   [7, 8, 9],
                   ])

df.loc[df.index.size] = [10, 20, 30]
```

Comment: `concat` can be at the top of a chain; did you try that? If it needs to be in the middle, are you aware of `df.pipe`?

Comment: Did you check the reasoning for the deprecation? Such "fluent" interfaces are [typically not considered Pythonic if they are supposed to work in-place, as we prefer to respect command-query separation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062423).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use method chaining, use [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = (df
      #.some_method()
       .pipe(lambda d: pd.concat(
             [d, pd.DataFrame([[10, 20, 30]],
                              columns=df.columns)],
             ignore_index=True)
             )
      #.some_other_method()
      )
```

Or, if adding the row is the first step:

```
out = (pd.concat([d, pd.DataFrame([[10, 20, 30]],
                                   columns=df.columns)],
                 ignore_index=True)
        #.other_methods()
      )
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2
0   4   5   6
1   7   8   9
2   1   6   4
3  10  20  30
```

Note that adding a new row is expensive as this creates a full new DataFrame. It's fine if you do it once or twice but don't do it in a loop or this will be very slow for large datasets.