# Pandas merge() has no effect on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am learning Python and am stuck on a homework question.
I understood that you could merge two dataframes together - but my output only works if I create a third dataframe.  Can anyone help tell me why?
I have two dataframes:

- df - a list of passengers on the Titanic and various fields - each has a PassengerId
- df_new - a list of passengers and new information about them - with a passenger ID called Pid

I want to combine the two using the two ID fields as the link.  If I create a new dataframe for the output like this it works perfectly so I know my syntax is good. I can check the output of df_final and see all the fields together:

```
df_final = df.merge(right=df_new, right_on='Pid', left_on='PassengerId', how='inner')
```

But the homework says to merge df_new into df. There is no error when I run below, but the original dataframe df is not updated with the new fields

```
df.merge(df_new, right_on='Pid', left_on='PassengerId', how='inner')
```

I have no idea why as this is the syntax we were given in the lecture.  I can set `df=` this and it works, but this should work as well?  Or does merge always require you to set the destination dataframe first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A merge **always** creates a third dataframe. [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) does not work in-place (that is, it cannot modify the existing dataframes).

If you look at other Pandas methods, like [`.rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) for example, they have an `inplace` parameter to enable in-place behaviour, but `.merge()` doesn't have that.

There are also other methods that *always* act in-place, like [`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), but you'll note that they return `None`, which is part of [a broader idea in Python to have command-query separation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1682601/4518341) ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13574259/4518341)); that is, if a function modifies an object, it doesn't also return that object. In contrast, if you look at the examples for `.merge()`, they return the result, e.g.

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey')
  lkey  value_x rkey  value_y
0  foo        1  foo        5
...
```

Comment: P.S. There might be more to this, like how Python variables work, Pandas design principles, or how the Python interactive interpreter works, but I'm not sure which part(s) exactly you're confused about. If you're still confused about anything, just ask.

Comment: thank you,  this answers the question perfectly and clearly.  the lack of inplace was mentioned earlier but without context I did not understand the significance.  I like to learn the rules first and we have just been given examples so far so I was a bit lost on merge as it did not work as I (wrongly ) expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
df.merge(df_new, ...
```

You wanted

```
df = df.merge(df_new, ...
```

This computes an intermediate value and assigns it to `df`,
discarding the old `df` contents.
It's much like the `df_final` assignment statement you mentioned,
and then we assign *that* to `df`.
But all in one go, without using that temp var.

---

I validated with pandas 2.2.0, running under python 3.11.7.

> the original dataframe df is not updated with the new fields

Yes, that is the correct and
[documented](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)
behavior.

> Returns:
>
> DataFrame
>
> ```
>    A DataFrame of the two merged objects.
> ```

Note the absence of an `inplace=` boolean option.

Having computed such a result DataFrame,
caller is certainly free to assign it to a variable.
This does not happen in the pandas documentation
example, and that is still fine and useful:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey')
  lkey  value_x rkey  value_y
0  foo        1  foo        5 ...
```

Note the `>>>` REPL prompt, which is commonly used in these docs.
The REPL will automatically and compactly
reveal many computed values, which is convenient for exposition.
The documentation deliberately avoids this equivalent
but more verbose style of exposition:

```
>>> df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey')
>>> print(df3) ...
```

We could re-assign `df1 = df1.merge(...` there, if desired,
and then we would still have to `print(df1)` to view its
updated contents.

Comment: thanks but as I say in the last sentence, I know that works, but according to my lecturer ( and the pandas refrence material) you should not need to assign the data to the dataframe - df1.merge(df2, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey') is the example given on the pandas website and should merge the data into df1, but they do not mention having to assign it?

Comment: In that example in the docs, the code is executed in the interactive interpreter and prints the result (which is a third dataframe). Simple example: if you start an interactive interpreter, and you type `x=5` then `y=2` then `x+y`, then `7` is printed, but the values of `x` and `y` have not changed.

Comment: thank you wjandrea, yes I an just cnfused and this is my first week trying to learn python, I was simply trying to learn if you have to declare what dataframe to merge to, it seems it is implied in a lot of examples so it is not clear when you are just learning.  I may also have missed something in the lecture as 4 hours is a lot of new things to take in!