# ValueError: needs to have a value for field "" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: python, django

Django Version: 1.10.4
Exception Type: ValueError

```
Exception Value:    
"<SchoolBook:  0 test1 Test2 Test3 2011 122>" needs to have a value for field "schoolbook" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

PLease help to avoid this error:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=256, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.slug = slugify(self.name, separator='_')
    return super(Subject, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class SchoolBook(models.Model):
    parent_subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
    year = models.SmallIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=True)
    autors = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=256, blank=True, unique=True)
    f_file = models.FileField(upload_to=directory_path)

def __str__(self):
    return '{0} {1} {2}'.format(
        self.name, self.autors, self.year)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        subject_name = [self.parent_subject.values()[i]['name'] for i in range(len(self.parent_subject.values()))]
        self.name = ' '.join(subject_name)
        self.slug = slugify("{} {} {} {} {}".format(self.name, self.autors,self.year, self.pages, self.c_class))
    return super(SchoolBook, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

the issue is when i am trying to save the object.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot access related objects of a many-to-many relation before the instance is saved! The instance must have an `id` for the intermediate m2n table to point its foreign key (by the name of `schoolbook`, hence the error message) to:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        super(SchoolBook, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    # process self.parent_subject (should be called ...subjects, semantically)
    super(SchoolBook, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Why calling super twice with same signature?

Comment: @DanielW. The first one provides the instance with a primary key, so the related objects can be created. The second one saves the updated `slug` that depended on the related objects.

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot to understand why my many to many did not work

Answer (score 0):

This is a minor correction to the (memorably named) @user2390182's answer.

I am not sure when it was introduced, but the `model.save()` method now has a `force_insert` parameter, which forces a SQL `INSERT` statement. However, this does not set `.pk` to None before saving.

Therefore just in case anything sets `force_insert=True` (eg, `factory-boy` does), the following code works, whereas @user2390182's second call to super().save will raise a duplicate key error:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        super(SchoolBook, self).save(force_insert, *args, **kwargs)
        force_insert = False
    # process self.parent_subject (should be called ...subjects, semantically)
    super(SchoolBook, self).save(force_insert, *args, **kwargs)
```

PS. `force_insert` is the first parameter, hence it can be passed up as a positional arg.