# NOT NULL constraint failed: portal_visitrequests.visitor_id

Tags: python, django

I am very new to django and I've been battling with this particular project for a while now. I get a not null constraint error every time I try and submit my form(which ultimately creates Visitor and VisitRequests objects). The error comes from this line of code...**visit_request = VisitRequests(staff=staff, visitor=visitor, comment=comment, token=token, status=None).save()**... Please view the code below.

**views.py**

```
def formpage(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        token=secrets.token_urlsafe(20)
        visitor_name=request.POST.get('visitorsname')
        comment=request.POST.get('comment')
        visit_type=request.POST.get('visit_type')
        visit_content='You have a waiting visitor'+'\n'+'Name:'+visitor_name+'\n'+'Purpose Of Visit:'+visit_type+'\n'+'Additional Comment:'+comment+'\n'+token
        staff_id=request.POST.get('staff')
        staff=Staff.objects.get(id=staff_id)
        staff_email=staff.staff_email
        req_comment = request.POST.get('req_comment')
        request_id = (request.POST.get('request_id'))
        visitor=Visitor(visitor_name=visitor_name).save()
        visit_request = VisitRequests(staff=staff, visitor=visitor, comment=comment, token=token, status=None).save()
```

**models.py**

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    staff_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    staff_email = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.staff_name

class Visitor(models.Model):
    visitor_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.visitor_name)

class VisitRequests(models.Model):
    staff=models.ForeignKey(Staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    visitor = models.ForeignKey(Visitor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment= models.TextField(default='')
    status= models.NullBooleanField()
    token=models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Comment: I would suggest put pdb statement before saving the object and see the errors. my first guess is one of the inputs to VisitRequest constructor is None.

Comment: Use create instead of save

Comment: @seuling. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is assuming Django's `save` returns the model object, which is not the case. You may want to read [Why does django ORM's `save` method not return the saved object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10936737/10657880) for further understanding.

In your case you can use [Django's create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#create) function to create and get the returned object:

```
visitor = Visitor.objects.create(visitor_name=visitor_name)
visit_request = VisitRequests.objects.create(staff=staff, visitor=visitor, comment=comment, token=token, status=None)
```

Comment: @B.obed If this answer helps, please select this answer