# Save Django Form wizard data to three models with related fields

Tags: django, django-views, django-formwizard, django-file-upload

I am working on a project that requires use of form wizard to populate three related models. The first model - `Listing` - has general data which has a `OneToOneField` relationship with the second model `(Property)`. The `Listing` model also has a many to many relationships with the third model `(ListingImages)`. In general, I am using 4 forms in the wizard. Here is the models definition
models.py

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    listing_type_choices = [('P', 'Property'), ('V', 'Vehicle'), ('B', 'Business/Service'), ('E', 'Events')]

    listing_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    listing_type = models.CharField(choices=listing_type_choices, max_length=1, default='P')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    location = PlainLocationField(based_fields=['city'], zoom=7, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    expires_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, null=True, blank=True
    )
    listing_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='list_owner'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.listing_title


def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
    title = instance.listing.listing_title
    slug = slugify(title)
    return "listings_pics/%s-%s" % (slug, filename)


class ListingImages(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename,
                              verbose_name='Listing Images')
    main_image = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Listing Images"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.listing.listing_title} Image'


class Property(models.Model):
    sale_hire_choices = [('S', 'Sale'), ('R', 'Rent')]
    fully_furnished_choices = [('Y', 'Yes'), ('N', 'No')]

    listing = models.OneToOneField(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(PropertySubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    for_sale_rent = models.CharField(choices=sale_hire_choices, max_length=1, default=None)
    bedrooms = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    bathrooms = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    rooms = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    land_size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available_from = models.DateField()
    car_spaces = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    fully_furnished = models.CharField(choices=fully_furnished_choices, max_length=1, default=None)
    desc = models.TextField()
    property_features = models.ManyToManyField(PropertyFeatures)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Here is the forms.py

```
    from django import forms
from .models import Listing, Property, Vehicle, Business, ListingImages
from django.forms import modelformset_factory

class ListingDetails(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ['listing_title', 'city', 'location']

class PropertyDetails1(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ['sub_category', 'for_sale_rent', 'bedrooms', 'bathrooms',
            'rooms', 'land_size', 'available_from', 'car_spaces', 'fully_furnished',
            'desc', 'currency', 'price'
        ]

class PropertyDetails2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ['property_features']

class ListingImagesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image_url = forms.ImageField(label='Listing Image',
        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        required=False
    )
    class Meta:
        model = ListingImages
        fields = ['image_url']

ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(ListingImages, form=ListingImagesForm, extra=3)
```

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import os
from .forms import ListingDetails, PropertyDetails1, PropertyDetails2, ListingImagesForm
from .models import ListingImages, Listing, Property
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.forms.models import construct_instance

class PropertyView(SessionWizardView):
    # formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=Images.objects.none())
    template_name = "listings/create_property.html"
    form_list = [ListingDetails, PropertyDetails1, PropertyDetails2, ListingImagesForm]
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'media'))
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        listing_instance = Listing()
        property_instance = Property()
        listing_instance.created_by = self.request.user
        listing_instance.listing_owner = self.request.user
        listing_instance.listing_type = 'P'
        for form in form_list:
            listing_instance = construct_instance(form, listing_instance, form._meta.fields, form._meta.exclude)
            property_instance = construct_instance(form, property_instance, form._meta.fields, form._meta.exclude)
        listing = listing_instance.save()
        property_instance.listing = listing
        property_instance.save()
        return HttpResponse('data saved successfully')
```

The problem that I am facing is that I am able to save the `Listing` model, but getting its primary id and using it to save the `Property` model is the problem. Again, the `ListingImages` model stores images related to the `Listing` model. How do I save these models to database considering that they are multiple?

Comment: Indentation error? Last three lines before `return` in `PropertyView` look as if they ought to be part of the loop over `form_list`. That aside, you need to clarify what you mean by "first model" "third model" etc.

Comment: The indentation is okay because those do not fall under the for loop. Let me clarify that model naming ASAP.

Comment: And just to clarify that the three line work well, the `listing = listing_instance.save()` is saving data to the database as expected. Problem comes with the line that follows since the primary key is not assigned as foreign key as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong is that as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936737/why-does-django-orms-save-method-not-return-the-saved-object),  model.save() does not return the saved object, but `None`.

So the last few lines of the above code should be

```
    listing_instance.save()
    property_instance.listing = listing_instance
    property_instance.save()
    return HttpResponse('data saved successfully')
```

Ditto saving a set of listing_images would be something like

```
    for li_obj in listing_image_instances:
         li_obj.listing = listing_instance # saved above
         li_obj.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The property model is now saving well. However, for images, I am getting the error `'ListingImages' object is not iterable`. I used your code above, after customizing it to fit my definitions of attributes.

Comment: I removed the iterration part and it is saving an individual file in the database correctly, so the problem is in handling the multiple images. How do I go about that?